# multi-threading in fedora

Tags: linux, multithreading, fedora

*I've written a multi-thread program with ptgread. My CPU is dual core. But the program does not run as parallel. I attached system monitoring as following. 
My question is, does support fedora13 multi-threading?* 
[image]

Comment: Without code, how is anyone supposed to help?

Comment: Normal Linux kernels always supports multithreading, whether you have a multicore CPU or not. Maybe your assumption that one thread will be allocated to one CPU and the other to the other CPU is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incomplete so this answer may not be effective. Will revise with more information.

However, few tips you should be able work out.

1. Are any threads waiting for the other?
2. IS there a dead-lock amongst the threads where both threads are effectively sleeping?
3. Are there too many I/O  involved? (wait on sockets, read, write on disk, even heavy printfs includes this)
4. Does any of the thread has long sleeps (usleep, nanosleep anyone..)

If there are any of the above condition true, even if the CPU is available, because active instruction set need to wait till effective back log is done.

Second limitation of your question is the measurement. You have chart that is system through put. Even if you have one CPU, the thread switching can be so transparent because the thread switch within matter of few (10s or 100s) of millisecond. And if each of your thread is running on same CPU - you can never say see when these threads switched. Infact the graph you are seeing is shared not only by your 2 threads - but so many processes that are running in system.

But as i said - i can only be more effective if you give complete details.